# How do I make MVC discard requests with verbs other than specified in the constraint?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC application I want behavior as was previously specified in `<httpHandlers>` in web.config, namely that if I register a handler like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="processData" verb="POST" path="processData" type="RightType, RightAssembly"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

then all requests to `/processData` that have verbs other than "POST" result in HTTP 404.

I tried to register a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    @"ProcessData", @"processData",
    new { controller = @"Api", action = @"ProcessData" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint( "POST" ) } );
```

and now once a request has a verb other than POST the route isn't matched, route resolution falls through and proceeds to the default page.

How do I make MVC produce an HTTP error message (code 404 or anything like that) once a path matches but a verb mismatches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just register another route with the verbs that you don't want and make that lead to a NotFound action.

Answer (score 0):

Routing works by following routes in the order specified until it finds one that matches. By adding the constraint you make this route fail and so it goes down the list to find the next matching route (your default).

To get the behaviour you want you need to have your route catch the request and then handle the error.

Take the constraint out of the route and on your controller do the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult processData(myModel myPostedModel)
{
    DoStuff();
    Return View();
}

public ActionResult processData()
{
    throw new HttpException(404);
}
```

I am assuming that you do model binding on your action method here because you do need differing method signatures. If not then you'll need to take off the HttpPost attribute and test for the request method there.